Fit a first polynomial trend surface raster and calculate it's global slope angle
For a given point location (x,y) and radius (meters), I want to fit a trend surface(linear) for each 30° sector around that point.

I have the 30° sectors and the underlying DEM raster. How can I fit a linear trend surface for each of the sector seperately using QGIS something similar to (ArcGIS Pro trend Surface) and calculate the slope of that linear trend surface. By slope here I don't mean pixelwise slope, I'm looking for one global slope angle value for that linear trend surface with the horizontal.

You had a tag for PyQGIS but have not presented any code so I’ve removed it. You also had a tag for SAGA but did not mention it in your question so to maintain focus on QGIS I removed that too.

I mentioned saga because SAGA is the processing algorithim provider for such a task e.g. polynomial regression etc

If it’s relevant to the question then I think it’s relevance needs to be mentioned in the question body.
